# How to combine results of two queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In order to calculate the total commission of sales agents in my company I run two queries on two different MySQL tables. Bot queries result a table with the agent name and the earned commission of that period. The reason I have two different tables is because they are different products with different columns.

Is there a way to combine the queries so that the total earned commission is given as a result? So the result from query 1 + result query 2.

These are the queries:

```
SELECT agent, SUM(vergoeding_partner) as sum 
FROM Sales s 
INNER JOIN Proposities p ON s.product_name = p.naam 
WHERE finalized_at > CURDATE() AND flow=165 
GROUP by agent;

SELECT agent, SUM(IF(eancode_e<>'' AND eancode_g<>'',vergoeding_partner*2, vergoeding_partner)) as sum 
FROM Transactions t 
INNER JOIN Proposities p ON t.productnaam = p.naam 
WHERE finalized_datetime > CURDATE() 
GROUP BY agent ORDER by sum DESC;
```

Comment: @Luuk Not really

Comment: After this union thing you can add the 2 values, like: `select agent, a+b from (select agent, a from query1 union all select agent, bfrom from query2) x group by agent`  Then x is needed as alias for the combination